# Prepend directory to $PATH in Centos 6

Tags: php, linux, ssh, centos6

I'm looking to globally prepend a directory to my $PATH variable in Centos6. Currently it is as follows:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

I would like it to become:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

I've already made a modification which changes the directory correctly for when I run "which php" but that doesn't seem to satisfy scripts that I execute which call php.

EDIT:

Why do I need to do this?

I am running a script called Composer (found here: https://getcomposer.org/), it is used for PHP development and then runs a command automatically which is "php artisan clear-compiled" (used in Laravel 5 projects).

When running the command "php artisan clear-compiled" myself I get no errors because it uses php7 which is configured for the root account. When the script runs it it errors because it is trying to execute using PHP 5.4 which isn't supported by artisan.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the PHP scrips? Or how you want to call them?

Comment: added more detail to the main question

Comment: I've found this similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos

Comment: Thanks, although that did work, composer is still complaining so it didn't affect what I needed but you've answered my question. This is another issue entirely